# Problems merging 4 columns into 1 and charting them in Data Studio

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-data-validation, google-data-studio, google-data-studio-charts

I would need to unify the data from columns Metod_1,Metod_2,Metod_3,Metod_4 and Metod_5 into a single column, but keeping the resolution date data associated to each row:

[image: gsheet]

Having resolved the above issue, in my Data Studio report I would need to get the above information to display in this way, filtered by "Resolved" date:

[image: chart example]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this formula in the first row of a free column:

```
=arrayformula( query( 
  { 
    flatten( iferror( 
      vlookup( BD!A1:A; BD!A1:A; sign(sequence(1; columns(BD!D1:H))); false ) 
    ) ) 
    \ 
    flatten(BD!D1:H) 
  }; 
  "where Col1 is not null 
   and Col2 is not null 
   order by Col1"; 
  1 
) )
```

Your sample spreadsheet's locale is Argentina, so the formula has to use `;` as argument separator and `\` as array expression horizontal separator.

You were using `=IFERROR(SPLIT(C2;";";TRUE;FALSE);" ")` to split values into columns. That introduces superfluous space characters in "empty" cells. Use this instead:

`=arrayformula( if( len(C2:C); split(C2:C; ";"; false; true); iferror(1/0) ) )`

Comment: thank you very much for your help!

I applied the formula you suggested, but it gives the following error:  

#VALUE: Unable to parse the query string for The QUERY function parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2.

(Apologies, my level of Google Sheets is not very high).

To help the understanding to be able to reproduce the error, I created this spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JtKo2_9wzdGC7jFddTpPyOHCkesVoSd6YWGwNjgreAE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Edited the answer. See your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: you are a genius! thanks for the help, it worked very well!

Comment: Testing the solution you created, I had a question about how I can add more data to the formula.

For example; from the "[BD V2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JtKo2_9wzdGC7jFddTpPyOHCkesVoSd6YWGwNjgreAE/edit#gid=484699902)" tab I would need to add the columns to the "[Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JtKo2_9wzdGC7jFddTpPyOHCkesVoSd6YWGwNjgreAE/edit#gid=1706709518)" tab:

- Labels
- Líder delivery

I would like to learn what part of the formulas I should modify to be able to scale the solution to N columns.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try using [{ array expressions }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276). You should ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741), so please post your new question in a new topic.